# Not being able to print API errors on VUE array

Tags: laravel, vue.js, rest, vuex

This is my code for the store index.js

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    jwt: '', // Almacena el token JWT
    error: '', // Almacena errores
    base_URL: 'http://localhost:8000/api/',
  },
  mutations: {
    // Definir una mutación para actualizar el token JWT
    setJwt(state, token) {
      state.jwt = token;
    },
    clearJwt(state) {
      state.jwt = '';
      console.log('JWT cleared'); // Agrega un mensaje de registro para verificar si se ejecuta esta mutación
    },
    // Definir una mutación para actualizar errores
    setError(state, errorMessage) {
      state.error = errorMessage;
    },
    setGlobalErrors(state, errors) {
      state.globalErrors = errors;
    },
  },
  actions: {

    /* INICIO LOGIN */
    async login({ commit }, { email, pass }) {
      try {
        const API_URL = `${this.state.base_URL}login`;
    
        const res = await fetch(API_URL, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            user_email: email,
            user_password: pass
          })
        });
    
        const response = await res.json();
    
        console.log('Response from server:', response);
    
        if ('errors' in response) {
          commit('setError', response.errors); // Almacena los errores de la API en el estado
          return false;
        }
    
        commit('setJwt', response.token);
        localStorage.setItem('jwt', response.token);
    
        return true;
      } catch (error) {
        commit('setError', error.message);
        console.error('Error during login:', error);
        throw new Error(error);
      }
    },
    /* FIN LOGIN */

    async logout({ commit }) {
      try {
        // Realiza cualquier otra limpieza necesaria, como borrar datos del usuario
        // ...
    
        commit('clearJwt');
        // Elimina el token JWT en el almacenamiento local
        localStorage.removeItem('jwt'); // Borra el token del almacenamiento local
        console.log('Logout successful'); // Agrega un mensaje de registro para verificar si se ejecuta esta acción
      } catch (error) {
        commit('setError', error.message);
        throw new Error(error);
      }
    },
  }
})
```

This is my code for the userLogin component:

```
<template>
    <form>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <!-- <label for="username" class="form-label">Email address</label> -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="user_email" name="user_email" v-model="userData.user_email" placeholder="Email address" />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <!-- <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label> -->
        <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="user_password" name="user_password" v-model="userData.user_password" placeholder="Password" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control form-control-lg" @click.prevent="authUser">Login</button>
    
    <!-- Mostrar errores al usuario -->
    <div v-if="errors.length > 0" class="alert alert-danger">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="error in errors" :key="error">{{ error }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    </form>
  </template>
  
  <script>

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        userData: {
                user_email: '',
                user_password: '',
            },
        errors: [],
      }
    },
    methods: {
      login() {
        // Aquí puedes agregar la lógica para enviar la solicitud de inicio de sesión al servidor
      },
      async authUser() {
  try {
    // En lugar de usar AuthService, puedes obtener los datos directamente del store
    const email = this.userData.user_email;
    const pass = this.userData.user_password;

    // Llama a la acción de login en el store
    const response = await this.$store.dispatch('login', { email, pass });

    if (response.status === 422) { // Verifica el código de estado HTTP
      const responseData = await response.json(); // Convierte la respuesta en un objeto JavaScript
      if (responseData.errors) { // Verifica si hay errores en la respuesta
        // Obtén los mensajes de error del objeto de errores
        const errorMessages = Object.values(responseData.errors).flat();
        // Almacena los mensajes de error en tu arreglo de errores para mostrarlos en tu componente
        this.errors = errorMessages;
      }
    } else if (response === true) { // Verifica si response es true
      // Guardar el token en el store si el inicio de sesión es exitoso
      // this.$router.push({ name: 'dashboard' });
      console.log('Response: ', response);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error durante el inicio de sesión:', error);
    alert('Error durante el inicio de sesión');
  }
},
    }
  }
  </script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.form-control-lg{
  font-size:16px;
}
</style>
```

And this is what I receive at my console from the API.

```
Response from server: 
{message: 'The user email field is required. (and 1 more error)', errors: {…}}
errors
: 
user_email
: 
['The user email field is required.']
user_password
: 
['The user password field is required.']
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
message
: 
"The user email field is required. (and 1 more error)"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

I'll show you the image:
[image]

Can you tell what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

I want to be able to print the error messages under the errors array which i declared at my Data().

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is because you haven't given an actual description explaining the issue.  "doesn't work" doesn't give us any clues.  Does `responseData.errors` contain the error messages you expect? Does `errorMessages` contain the formatted messages you expect?  These can be easily debugged with simple console.logs.  What gets displayed in the DOM, and have you used the inspector or devtools?